# Is it possible to step-through debug Xamarin code running under Xamarin.UITest driven by NUnit?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

Is it possible to step-through debug Xamarin code running under `Xamarin.UITest` driven by NUnit? Breakpoints in the test code hit, but breakpoints in the Xamarin code do not. F5 debugging the app in Visual Studio Emulator for Android also hits the breakpoints.

Here's my setup:

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2017 Update 2
- Xamarin 4.5.0.486
- Xamarin.Android SDK 7.3.1.2
- Nunit 2.6.4
- NUnitTestAdapter 2.1.1

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you looking to debug the Xamarin.UITest code, or the Xamarin.Android code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to debug the app-code when running UI tests.

Comment: Just to expand on this, the reason for this is because the UI tests are actually being run against the compiled app, in this case an APK; (though could be an IPA or a .app on Mac.)

Comment: the game changed a while ago, it's possible.